# MySQL composite key - unique combinations

Tags: mysql

Suppose there is table with columns `a` and `b`, and with composite unique key from `a,b` pair. And there is row `a=1, b=2`.

So I can not insert another row `a=1, b=2`, that's ok.

But how could I deny in this situation also inserting row `a=2, b=1` ?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (`a` INT, `b` INT); 
ALTER TABLE `t` ADD UNIQUE(`a`, `b`); 
INSERT INTO `t` (`a`, `b`) VALUES ('1', '2'); 
INSERT INTO `t` (`a`, `b`) VALUES ('2', '1');
```

The second insert works, though I expect it will fail.

Comment: It sounds like it'd work that same way for `a=2`, `b=1` just as it would for `a=1`, `b=2` so you already have the answer to this question. This would mean you can only have 1 record in the table where `a=2` and `b=1` just as it'd work for the `a=1` and `b=2` for that record -- only one allowed with that unique key combo.... Sounds like you got it under control to me.... i.e. `UNIQUE KEY 'uk_ab' ('a','b')` this would work the same for BOTH as in your example from your question.

Comment: `UNIQUE KEY uk_ab (a,b)` allows inserting `a=2,b=1` when `a=1,b=2` exists :(

Comment: Have updated post with example.

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct, it will allow one record of those same values so that sounds correct to me. `a=2,b=1` is one record and `a=1,b=2` is another record. You can only have ONE record where each of those are true where a and b equal some value so your two examples are different and not the same so that is correct. Try to insert another record where those are the same again and confirm it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Since MySQL 7.5.3

you can define [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) and have a unique index on them. For example you can say that `concat(least(a, b), ',', greatest(a, b))` must be unique. Then you can define a *virtual* column with the same expression and set a unique index on it.

```
create table t (
  a int,
  b int,
  virtual_unique varchar(50) as (concat(least(a, b), ',', greatest(a, b))),
  primary key (a, b),
  unique index (virtual_unique)
);
```

When you try to insert `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)`, you get an error:

> ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '1,2' for key 'virtual_unique'

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kGfLRdvaj8mQhxF69PRPV6/0)

Note that in this case the columns should not contain the used delimiter (`,` in this case) which is always the case for integers.

You can also define a composite unique key on virtual columns:

```
create table t (
  a int,
  b int,
  virtual_min int as (least(a, b)),
  virtual_max int as (greatest(a, b)),
  primary key (a, b),
  unique index (virtual_min, virtual_max)
);
```

Your insert statements wil raise:

> ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'virtual_min'

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9axVjNf4hn2PNSSHL3QRS6/0)

Here is no issue with the delimiter.

Note that `SELECT *` queries will show those virtual columns.

#### Since MySQL 8.0.13

you can also [index expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts), without a need for unused virtual columns:

```
create table t (
  a int,
  b int,
  primary key (a, b),
  unique index ((least(a,b)), (greatest(a,b)))
);
```

Your inserts would raise the following error:

> Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'functional_index'

[db<>fidle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e631a4053eff93c761586d2f859b1439)

Answer (score 2):

You can't with an key/index definition. From a DB perspective the values of (1,2) and (2,1) will always be different.

The solution would be to ensure that e.g. `a` always has the higher value than `b` or vice versa. You could either ensure this in the application that adds the record or as a DB trigger.

See also: [Unique combination key MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22085/unique-combination-key-mysql) which has an example on how to do this with a trigger.